# My cat vomited string and I pulled it

Tags: cats, health

My cat ate a piece of string (not a thick one. A slim one used for sewing). She passed it through her mouth and seeing her struggle I did the stupid thing of pulling on it because I panicked. I pulled very gently, after she eliminated a ball of string, and I encountered no resistance while pulling. She stood still while I pulled, except for the last centimeters of string. The string I pulled was straight, with no knots.

After this, she vomited 2-3 times a clear liquid, sometimes foamy. She seemed to have no changes in behaviour other than not eating as much as usual.

I had to leave the house for some time for work, and came back home at 2 am, 8 hours after last seeing her. She vomited once more after I arrived,but she looks tired (it's still 2 am). I found no other vomit puddles. There is no vet opened at this hour but I'll get her to one first thing in the morning.

Is there anything I should know until sunrise?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

So, some updates for those interested or that might stumble upon the same issue:

As I commented to my question, I took her to the vet everyday and we have tried medication and feeding her through IV, because the chunk of string she vomited was very large. However, that seemed to be a mistake because she was not getting any better. We decided to try surgery.

The doctor found another huge amount of string in her digestive system, from her esophagus all the way to the end of her intestines. The surgery was complicated and a piece of intestine had to be removed due to it becoming necrotic.

After a few days, we had to perform another surgery because of some liquids accumulating in her bowels. After this second surgery she started eating again and seems better now, but still weakened and prone to complications because of the things she has been through.

My advice for fellow pet owners is: Even if nothing shows up on the X-rays, as was our case (Only some twisted intestine showed up), don't delay explorative surgery too much.