# Why my cat literally swallows whatever thread she gets?

Tags: cats, behavior, diet

I have noticed this weird behavior behavior in my cat. She simply loves any thread, whether it is cotton thread, woollen thread or plastic thread. She starts chewing and swallowing the thread.

Today I found her chewing on a long thread of wool. I immediately scolded her and started pulling out the woolen thread from her mouth. To my astonishment I pulled out literally 3 meters of the woollen thread from her mouth. (Probably from her stomach. I had to pull the thread with force. But I did not at that time look inside her mouth.)

So why does she shows this weird behavior? Is this harmful? If harmful how to modify her behavior so that she no longer does this?

Comment: Eating things that are not food is known as pica. There are many questions already about cats and pica. Specific to string, string can be bad because it's long and can get tangled up, and possibly injure your cat internally. Tinsel, which is string like but plastic, is particularly bad. Other strings are not as risky. Make sure to keep them all away from your cat.

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18370/my-cat-vomited-string-and-i-pulled-it

Comment: @Henders now this post's answer is really giving panic to me. But my cat doesn't seem sick.

Comment: You removed the string your cat was eating, so unless the cat has eaten additional string, there is no risk. There's even a pretty decent chance if it eats another regular string, it will pass with no incident. But with inedible things, there's always some risk that it will be bad. If you know it's eaten string, monitor your cat for signs, like no longer eating, and watch the litterbox. Strings are not digestible, so you will see it pass.  If your cat stops eating or seems distressed, take it to the vet.